# Calculating Thrust for Contra-Rotating Propellers

Tags: propulsion, thrust

How do I calculate the thrust of ducted contrarotating propellers?

Is there any formula or website calculator or would it have to be done through experimenting with scale replicas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one analysis that gives you information .

[image]

Source : http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/arc/rm/2218.pdf

Comment: is there not a way to do this for just the motor, this equation involves drag of fuselage etc

Comment: Drag is included for the central portion of the propellor or have you got a new design that the propellors don't have a central mounting or drive point?